# Connecting an Android device through ADB in Arch Linux 64-bit

Tags: linux, android, arch-linux

I'm trying to connect Nexus 5 through ADB in my Arch Linux but it's refusing to connect. I've istalled the SDK but I think I need to set udev rules and install some 32-bit packages. I've successfully connected my device in Debian but having a problem in Arch System.

Comment: could you elaborate your problem,whats the problem which you are facing at arch system?

Comment: buried under setting look for developer, debug, or etc option and turn it on

Answer (score 2):

I think, this does not work out of the box in Archlinux. For popular devices, it's usually enough to install the package [android-udev](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-udev/) from AUR.

If the device is not listed in there, you can add the rule by yourself: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#Adding_udev_Rules

If you don't know your device ids, this will help:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#Figure_Out_Your_Device_Ids

I've done this a few weeks back for my Fairphone and it worked fine.

Edit: If I recall correctly, installing 32-bit packages was not necessary in my case. Could be, that they were already installed, though.